# Use golang remove VARIATION SELECTOR-16 from string?

Tags: go

I have the string: 9

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=9%EF%B8%8F

It is contains 2 unique character codes, DIGIT NINE and a Variation Selector 16. How do I strip this variation selector to return:

DIGIT NINE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decode the query string, then trim all unicode Variation Selectors from the string.

```
s = strings.TrimFunc(s, func(r rune) bool {
    return unicode.In(r, unicode.Variation_Selector)
})
```

https://play.golang.org/p/qvuWIH52mdN